# Devart donetconnect connector do not read arabic string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, devart, dotconnect

In my winforms Application, I want to display the content of my PostgreSQL database in a grid view. I am using Entity Framework 5.0 and devart dotconnect connector. I have some arabic values in my database that cannot be displaying in gridview, they are coded. He return s some thing like that `Ø´Ø§Ø±Ø¹ Ø§Ù„ÙˆÙƒØ§Ù„Ø© -`

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting the Unicode connection string parameter value to True. 
To do it in Entity Developer, open Database Explorer,  right-click the Database Connection and select Edit Connection Properties from the shortcut menu, click the Advanced button. Set Unicode to True in the opened dialog box and save changes.

If it doesn't help, please [contact us](http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) with more information about this issue, e g.:

- if possible, send us a small test project, with which this error could be reproduced;
- the version of PostgreSQL server, etc.